# Mapping multiple classes to a single entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I recently read this article again: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/04/20/types-of-cqrs/
Please see the code below from type 1:

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    public void Save(Customer customer) { /* … */ }
    public Customer GetById(int id) { /* … */ }
    public IReadOnlyList<CustomerDto> Search(string name) { /* … */ }
}
```

Notice that there are two separate objects for Customers i.e. Customer and CustomerDto. I believe entity framework only allows you to map one entity to one class. How does it cater for the code above?

Comment: The [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) classes are not saved to the database. The properties are mapped to the entities.

Comment: @Jason, are you saying that the Search method uses a tool like automapper to map Customer to CustomerDto?

Comment: DTOs are usually classes that aren't mapped to the entity directly - they provide a way to transfer objects without requiring that the receiver have any reference to EF or the backend data store. So, EF doesn't need to cater to the code above...

Comment: Yes, AutoMapper can be a helpful tool in this case. But you can do manual projections as well.

Comment: @Jason, so EF still returns a Customer but this is mapped to a CustomerDTO either through a projection or automapper.  Is that correct?

Comment: The repository exposes DTO classes to its clients. The implementation details uses entities. This isolates EF within the data layer. The DTO properties might not even be a 1:1 mapping to an entity -- there could be many entity classes involved yet a relatively flat DTO.

Comment: Vladimir Khorikov (the author of the article) has a few repositories on Github. One of them contains this file: https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/blob/master/DddInPractice.Logic/SnackMachines/SnackMachineRepository.cs. Although it's written against NHibernate, you can see how he does the mapping as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) classes are not saved to the database. The properties are mapped to the entities.

```
var query = db.Customer.First(c => c.id == id);
var customerDto = Map<CustomerDto>(query);
```

The repository exposes DTO classes to its clients. The implementation details uses entities. This isolates EF within the data layer.

The DTO properties might not even be a 1:1 mapping to an entity -- there could be many entity classes involved yet a relatively flat DTO.

```
public class CustomerInfoDto
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    // ... some customer properties
    public int CustomerExtendedId { get; set; }
    // ... some additional properties
}

var info =  from c in db.Customers
            join e in db.CustomerExtended on c.Id equals e.CustomerId
            select new CustomerInfoDto
            {
                CustomerId = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name,
                CustomerExtendedId = e.Id,
                LastAccess = e.LastAccess
            };
```